# How to change only a part of string in a MongoDB field?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Data in my collection looks like this:

```
[
{
  "_id": "6396c58284bfad036f960236",
  "one": "https://www.good.com/vgeiwedewegoeg73739825/vefiefdejfjho_dewfwfe_vkhgderikgfjficakjgcao",
  "four": "https://cdn56-img.good-cdn.com/efvefiefdeoqefefs/thumbs169ll/cc/d7/55/ccd755eb9438306f175f1e580168f9dc/ccd755eb9438306f175f1e580168f9dc.15.jpg"
},
{
  "_id": "6396c58284bfad036f960237",
  "one": "https://www.good.com/egvgiddfefohng73739803/ddesfejhfefhji_cojhfhupkjglehfhs",
  "four": "https://img-in.good-cdn.com/qytviefdsgehhosgfd/thumbs169ll/cf/82/eb/cf82ebf864927ca9dc2bf4d4e50f7421/cf82ebf864927ca9dc2bf4d4e50f7421.15.jpg"
},
{
  "_id": "6396c58284bfad036f95fe4d",
  "one": "https://www.good.com/ehvhiththhteonbv72876078/fggommjcavnhhbdokjh_fghdoiejgjhnthfrkhfgo_efdjhreffefffa_efbrhfjanqhfhgfuinjfhhewffa",
  "four": "https://img-cn.good-cdn.com/efevidefeeeoseffe/thumbs169ll/5b/90/86/5b90867e30e054540fb3ef891ee617c2/5b90867e30e054540fb3ef891ee617c2.15.jpg"
},
{
  "_id": "6396c58284bfad036f96023c",
  "one": "https://www.good.com/svsdidghjdujeofd73739693/efwafereefefhoertusfe_oitagrhreggresggomeer-_agrhaiggdaddyegsgeegxrg",
  "four": "https://img-us.good-cdn.com/qwvzzifefdgregefeofes/thumbs169ll/55/5f/a0/555fa0ff486f551400ff82e302ac96b7/555fa0ff486f551400ff82e302ac96b7.14.jpg"
}
]
```

In the four field of this data there are different subdomains, but I want to use only one subdomain `https://cdn56-img.good-cdn.com/` like this:

```
[
{
  "_id": "6396c58284bfad036f960236",
  "one": "https://www.good.com/vgeiwedewegoeg73739825/vefiefdejfjho_dewfwfe_vkhgderikgfjficakjgcao",
  "four": "https://cdn56-img.good-cdn.com/efvefiefdeoqefefs/thumbs169ll/cc/d7/55/ccd755eb9438306f175f1e580168f9dc/ccd755eb9438306f175f1e580168f9dc.15.jpg"
},
{
  "_id": "6396c58284bfad036f960237",
  "one": "https://www.good.com/egvgiddfefohng73739803/ddesfejhfefhji_cojhfhupkjglehfhs",
  "four": "https://cdn56-img.good-cdn.com/qytviefdsgehhosgfd/thumbs169ll/cf/82/eb/cf82ebf864927ca9dc2bf4d4e50f7421/cf82ebf864927ca9dc2bf4d4e50f7421.15.jpg"
},
{
  "_id": "6396c58284bfad036f95fe4d",
  "one": "https://www.good.com/ehvhiththhteonbv72876078/fggommjcavnhhbdokjh_fghdoiejgjhnthfrkhfgo_efdjhreffefffa_efbrhfjanqhfhgfuinjfhhewffa",
  "four": "https://cdn56-img.good-cdn.com/efevidefeeeoseffe/thumbs169ll/5b/90/86/5b90867e30e054540fb3ef891ee617c2/5b90867e30e054540fb3ef891ee617c2.15.jpg"
},
{
  "_id": "6396c58284bfad036f96023c",
  "one": "https://www.good.com/svsdidghjdujeofd73739693/efwafereefefhoertusfe_oitagrhreggresggomeer-_agrhaiggdaddyegsgeegxrg",
  "four": "https://cdn56-img.good-cdn.com/qwvzzifefdgregefeofes/thumbs169ll/55/5f/a0/555fa0ff486f551400ff82e302ac96b7/555fa0ff486f551400ff82e302ac96b7.14.jpg"
}
]
```

How to modify it using MongoDB aggregation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple option is to use `$concat` and `$split`:

```
db.collection.updateMany({},
[
  {$set: {
      four: {
        $concat: [
          "https://cdn56-img.good-cdn.com/",
          {$last: {$split: ["$four", ".com/"]}}
        ]
      }
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/F8cMcVusjp4)

- Assuming first part must end with ".com/" and that other parts do not contain it. Otherwise you can elaborate the query to support other cases

Comment: Error: the update operation document must contain atomic operators got this error when using in mongodb shell, it's working in online mongodb playground

Comment: What is your mongodb version?

Comment: my version is '6.0.4'

Comment: it's also working in compass aggregation.

Comment: There is no reason for it not to work with this version under the assumptions above. Try to find a specific document that cause this issue. Try execute the query on few documents first, or create a collection with the 4 documents of the sample data and test it on it.

Comment: Maybe my mongodb shell code is wrong. Sorry